# IMediaControl::stop hangs when there is no signal

Tags: c++, directshow

I have a problem that seems to be very common in Google, but it didn't help me. When my app is trying to close everything, the last function called before releasing objects is IMediaControl::stop. Everything is OK when there is signal. But when I launch app without signal (or terminate it while app is working) program never returns from stop(). What's more, if I provide signal while it's already hanged everything comes back to normal and program unhangs and exits correctly.

This is a part of my code in main:

```
hr = connectFilters(pGraph, pCaptureDevice, AUDIO_INPUT_DEVICE_PIN_NAME,
pAnalyzerFilter, SPDIF_ANAL_FILTER_PIN_NAME);
if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    // run the graph
    hr = pControl->Run();
    if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {        
        // wait for UI thread to finish
        pFilterObject->WaitForThread();

        // stop the graph and exit
        pControl->Stop();
    }
}

releaseObjects();
return 0;
```

Google suggests deadlock (and indeed it is) caused by some threads waiting for each other. The UI thread seems not to be the problem, because I did an DLL based on this app without Window and the problem is just the same.

Big thanks in advance,

eclipse

**Edit**:

I have only two filters: source and transform. The problem is for sure in transform filter, because program runs fine without it. TCould it be the problem of not released buffers or samples somewhere? I don't know exactly how DirectShow works but maybe some extra things need to be done if there is no signal?

**Edit 2**:

I found out in Google that someone solved this problem by stopping source filter before stopping the graph. I did the same and it also hangs... I use this to get source filter:

```
hr = pFG2->AddSourceFilterForMoniker(pMoniker, pContext, wszName, &pSource);
*ppF = pSource;
(*ppF)->AddRef();
```

When I attach VS debugger it says that it can't display code, so I think it is somewhere in MS code. Even if I comment my function processing IMediaSamples it still hangs. Now I run out of the ideas what is wrong. I also tried stopping and removing filters from the graph in different ways.

Comment: It is the deadlock. One of the filters is failing you, you need to find which one exactly.

Comment: @Roman R. Can you say how can I check it? Or what could be wrong? DirectShow isn't my cup of tea so I don't even know where to look...

Comment: Remove filters from graph until it starts working fine. Because it is some of the filters failing, it is important what fitlers are there in first place, what is the topology of the graph.

Comment: I did as you said. Details in main post.

Comment: If you found that your filter freezes the execution, then why don't you attach your debugger and see where exactly it is frozen. Eventually it should be locked right in your code.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when trying to send the incoming image from a background thread up to the WPF window. Everything was fine until I tried to stop the mediacontrol or release anything.

The problem was with a dispatcher call of the action to get it to the UI thread. I temporarily commented out the call, which stopped the video from showing up on the screen at all, but I could break at any time in the samplegrabber and see it was still actually running.

Manually separating the image across threads is what needed to happen. Something in the generic functions keeps a reference around, so the com objects

To fix it, I created a dispatchertimer in the window, set its interval to 1ms, its callback to a function that does the UI update, and then in the grabber, had the buffercb event save the frame to a standalone variable and enable the timer.

Here is a brief look at what I ended up with:

```
    InteropBitmap newbmp;
    DispatcherTimer refreshTimer;
    refreshTimer = new DispatcherTimer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1), DispatcherPriority.Render, ontimer, this.Dispatcher);
    videoSampleCB.newframearrived += capGrabber_NewFrameArrived;

    void capGrabber_NewFrameArrived(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        newbmp = videoSampleCB.newimage;
        refreshTimer.IsEnabled = true;
    }
    void ontimerobject sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.BitmapSource = newbmp;
        refreshTimer.IsEnabled = false;
    }
class VideoSampleGrabberCallBack : ISampleGrabberCB  
{
        event eventhandler newframearrived;

        public InteropImage newimage;
        public int BufferCB(double sampleTime, IntPtr buffer, int bufferLen)
        {
             newimage = ...
             newframearrived(this, eventargs.empty);
        }
}
```